# JavaScript: Is it possible to attach an image into email only using javaScript?

Tags: javascript, email, frontend, email-attachments

I have a JavaScript app written for iOS iPresent application. It provides a user with some calculation. At the end, the results are taken and are sent in an email as a plain text. This behavior is achieved in a following way:

```
var emailSubject = 'Subject';

//email template
var emailMessage = '' +

    'Dear Mr. / Mrs.,[BR]' +

    '[BR]' +

    'Lorem ipsum ...' +

    '[BR]' +

    Your result is: '[RESULT]'     
;
```

The following function takes an email template, fill it with data and then opens a mailing dialogue.

```
openMailbox: function() {

        var message,
            Message,
            br = '%0D%0A'
        ;

        message = emailMessage
            .replace(/\[BR\]/g, '%0D%0A' )
            .replace(/\[RESULT\]/g, result )
            .replace(/&/, '%26')    

        Message = '' +
            'mailto:' +
            '?subject=' + emailSubject +
            '&body=' + message
        ;

        window.location.href = Message;

    },
```

Such email is just a plain text. Is it possible to enhance the way the email looks somehow? Add some styling for example, attach an image or pdf file in it, but only using front end technologies such as JavaScript, HTML, CSS?

Comment: No, a plain-text email is **plain text**. If you want to add images, you need to send an HTML email, and use an `<img>` tag. In any case, this has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: Can we really send mails using javascript? Can you show us some of your code so we can help?

Answer (score 0):

Pure theoreticly - you can. But it is for sure no the best idea!

Just to be clear. An email, is composed of several parts:

- Service headers. Here can be indicated address where to send email, address from, return path, subject, dkim signature, dmarc politics and many others.
- Email body. The message itself.
- Email attachments.

On the client you should generate only the body of the message. Well, pure theoretically you can build the whole letter there (adding all needed headers) and then just pass it to the mail server, but most probably it would not be a good solution.

Backend is much more better place to do it, you should pass there only the email body.

Once again, pure theoretically you can add an image attachment to the message body, by generating a base 64 string from the image and appending it to the letter with needed headers, like these:

```
------------F81BD43094AAFAF6EC4AE17F5F68753C
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: image/png; filename="facebook.png"
Content-Disposition: inline; charset=utf-8; filename="facebook.png"
Content-ID: <facebook.png>
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=
```

But in this case, you are creating not just the body of the letter but the letter itself, and it needs other headers. Like:

```
Delivered-To: email@email.com
Return-Path: <email@email.com>
From: =?utf-8?B?0JDQu9C10LrRgdCw0L3QtNGA?= <email@email.com>
Subject: =?utf-8?B?YWRhZA==?=

------------F81BD43094AAFAF6EC4AE17F5F68753C
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----------30F28BDC77E3693E345BC2E04E6615BC"

------------30F28BDC77E3693E345BC2E04E6615BC
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head></head>
<body><div align=left>MESSAGE BODY</div>
<hr size=1><div align=left style="height:25px">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this tip. I am currently trying it, but I am not sure how should I send such email. As you can see in my question, I use mailto to send messages. Is there a different way to send an email on client side using JavaScript only?

Comment: The email is sent by the server not by the client. You are just redirecting to the needed page: ` window.location.href = Message;` with needed params in query string (subject, message body etc). There, a backend script processes all those params and sends an email. I doubt very much that it will process images attachments as a base64 encoded string. You should better see what params can be accepted there.

Comment: No, base64 encoding is not allowed in body. :/ Too bad! I was hoping to solve this problem on the client side only...

Comment: I insist you to do it on the backend. :) It ain't good idea at all, to do it one the client.

Comment: My boss insists on frontend. :D